# Issues with adding IPv6 to Tomcat webserver

Tags: xml, tomcat, vpn, pritunl

SO community! :)

I currently have a Tomcat server setup which is only reachable via VPN on IPv4.

I now wanted to add IPv6 but no matter what I tried it doesn't want to work.

I really can't think of any reason why it wouldn't work, it's very frustrating as I can't tell my staff to disable IPv6 support on their router.

Here's my original IPv4 setup

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="xxx\.119\.xx\.15x"/>
```

Here's what i tried so far

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="xxx\.119\.xx\.15x|2xxx:4xx:xxx:1bd6"/>
```

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="xxx\.119\.xx\.15x|::1|2xxx:4xx:xxx:1bd6"/>
```

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="xxx\.119\.xx\.15x|::1|2xxx:4xx:xxx:1bd6::64"/>
```

Any ideas? :/

Comment: Try using PING from a cmd.exe window to make sure you have a route to the IP.  You can also try from cmd.exe on remote machine to verify IP >IPConfig/all

Comment: Did all that. routes look fine, (IPv4 Works btw, just not IPv6)

Comment: IPV4 routes are ok.  What about IPV6 routes?

Comment: 1) DOes the vpn support ipv6? 2) is tomcat configured to bind to an [ipv6 address](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html)?

Comment: Yup, VPN supports IPv6 my tries to configure tomcat are above but none worked, according to the tomcat docs it should tough, which really confuses me.

Comment: `<Valve>` is for access control only bid address is configured at `<connector>` configuration and depending on tomcat version at `preferIPv4Stack` JAVA_OPTS

Comment: *bind address is configured at <connector> and depending on tomcat version, at [`java.net.preferIPv4Stack`, `java.net.preferIPv6Addresses`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) on `JAVA_OPTS`